# svn: E170001 : Authorization failed

Tags: svn

I am trying to execute the following commands:

```
svn checkout --username=shohrab svn+ssh://shohrab@svn.code.sf.net/p/dbprojecthft/code-0/ dbprojecthft-code-0
cd dbprojecthft-code-0
mkdir trunk branches tags
svn add trunk branches tags
svn ci -m "Add initial directories"
```

For the last command I am getting `svn: E170001: Authorization failed` error. After trying few hours on this error I am giving up.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have commit permission?

Comment: Are you using `svnserve` to host the repository?

Comment: @Blorgbeard: user 'shohrab' is an admin user. So  think admin should have commit permission.

Comment: @user1163650, specify username and password on committing too

Answer (score 5):

The error `svn: E170001: Authorization failed` says what it says; it occurs only when your user account does not have permissions to access the selected resource or when you provided invalid authentication credentials. In case of invalid credentials you'll see additional errors.

As far as I can see, you can checkout the project therefore you have Read access, but the commit fails since you don't have Write access OR since there was some authentication related-issue. So you should double-check

- that the URL that you enter to checkout the project is valid,
- that you specify the correct username and password to authenticate to the server,
- that your user account has Read / Write access to the project you attempt to commit to.

Comment: Also, don't forget to check that the repository itself is not read-only; that is, check that conf/svnserve.conf has either anon-access or auth-access set to write.

Comment: This is not accurate. The error is miss leading, for me the issue was two things, missing svnserve.conf that directed to the correct authentication and initializing the sync for the first time after creating a repo

Comment: @Elyahu my answer assumes that the server-side part is configured properly.

Comment: @bahrep That was my point, this error might notify in some cases that the repo is not configured properly

Answer (score 5):

The E170001 error also appears for repository updates (commits) if svnserve has been invoked with the -R (--read-only) option.

Comment: This happened to me when my admin changed the repo's permissions.

Answer (score 1):

As previously said here the error directing you to check your authentication, but it can be in several places, that you might need to check:

1. Is your username in passwd and authz file is properly defined ?
2. Is your conf/svnserve.conf direct you properly to the desired authentication method ?
3. Is your repo is open for wring on the OS level ? (chmod 777 for UNIX)
4. Is you repo inistialize ?

You can understand more if you try to run either of the "cvn list" or "svnsync" command check usage for more info

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you must to look at Preferences->General->Network Connections.
And to make sure that svn server is available.

Answer (score -3):

Because this entry turned up first in google and because SVN's error messages were written by Captain Obvious' third half-cousin's step brother, I just want to comment here that I was receiving the Unauthorized error message myself and just couldn't figure it out. Using file:// every thing worked fine: update/commit no problem. But when going via snv:// *boom* no auth for you. I could checkout but not commit. I was thinking maybe the creds wheren't getting through and I was being treated as an anonymous user, but no that wasn't it. Maybe my .conf file was not being read. But no that wasn't it because it knew my realm name. Turns out the default settings in /etc/sysconfig/svnserve for the the svnserve daemon have a **-R** option set. **-R** stands for **READONLY**, so it's not so much that I'm not authorized to access but rather that the whole server is set to fail. Would have been nice if there was a message that said, "Hey stupid, your server is read only. You may want to check that." In this case Auth Failed is not exactly the right error message because my auth did not fail, it was the write that failed due to the read only option being set.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It'll be great if you format your answer so that it is easy to read.